# How to model a shared layer in keras?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, keras-layer

I want to train a model with a shared layer in the following form:

```
x --> F(x)
          ==> G(F(x),F(y))
y --> F(y)
```

`x` and `y` are two separate input layers and `F` is a shared layer. `G` is the last layer after concatenating `F(x)` and `F(y)`.

Is it possible to model this in Keras? How?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [Keras functional API](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/) for this purpose:

```
from keras.layers import Input, concatenate

x = Input(shape=...)
y = Input(shape=...)

shared_layer = MySharedLayer(...)
out_x = shared_layer(x)
out_y = shared_layer(y)

concat = concatenate([out_x, out_y])

# pass concat to other layers ...
```

Note that `x` and `y` could be the output tensors of any layer and not necessarily input layers.

Comment: are both out_x , out_y using the same weights?

Comment: @Amirhessam They are output of the same layer with same weights, though given different inputs (i.e. `x` and `y`).

Comment: is it necessary to use the concatenate operation here? can't out_x be given to another layer?

Comment: @vampiretap Sure, you can feed `out_x` to different layers. The concatenation layer is used here because the OP explicitly mentioned this in their question: "G is the last layer after concatenating F(x) and F(y)".

Comment: What happens during learning?  Is it well-documented?